# SQL - selecting multiple dates from a table for unique ID's - part 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gordon got me pretty straight on my former question and now I've learned a lot more :).  my query now looks like this:

```
select ident, min(input_date) as 'date requested',
     min(case when op='u' and user IN (lists tech's names)) as 'date assigned'
     max(case when status='closed' then date end) as 'date completed'
     max(case when op='u' then user end) as 'tech'
from table
```

so this give me all that i want except the column that's labelled as 'tech'.  for the majority of the results, i get the correct results but for a handful it gives me either the wrong tech or the 'user'

[image]

so I've added a field so you can better understand - it's field called 'role'.  when i run this query, i never want the person listed as 'user' in the role column to be listed as 'tech'.  in query above, it lists the user instead of tech and it's always in cases where the user updated their request.  so if you look at the table, in ident 1, tom is user and harry is tech.  harry assigned it to himself on 2/2; however, tom updated request (to give more info) after harry assigned it.  running the above query, will result in tom being listed as the tech in the tech field.  my guess is b/c of max and tom is after harry alphabetically.

so i have 5 tech's to track (only 2 listed in table - bertha & harry).  if i add an IN clause so that it reads like this:
    max(case when op='u' and user IN ('bertha','harry',etc) then user end) as 'tech'

the results is it always gives me the last tech alphabetically rather than the one who assigned it/closed it.

my goal is to have the tech who assigns & closes it to be listed.  if the request has not been assigned then the 'tech' field should read null.

the date fields all have time stamps so i could go about it that way and i guess i could target their role as well.

i know that max is probably the problem as the tech could assign it then the user could update but if i put IN statement in there I don't get why it lists a tech who's not associated w/that ident.

finally, the other scenario, in ident 2, bertha actually takes the assignment away from harry so i need to say bertha;  however, harry will always be the one reported in field - probably due to max()

thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Your query has several syntax issues. No group by, missing parts of case expressions...and of course MAX(tech) will return the last one alphabetically, that is what MAX is doing there. Sounds like you might want ROW_NUMBER instead???

Comment: I guess i don't understand why i need group by and what parts of case expressions are missing?  everything works fine except for the very small # of entries where this is occurring.  row_number where user IN?

Comment: If you don't understand why you need a group by to return non-aggregated values in a query with aggregate data you need to read the basics about aggregation. You have the syntax correct for 2 of the 3 case expressions.